# Java String split() enclosing bodies

Tags: java, regex, string, split, io

I am trying to split a latex.bib file which follows the following format:

```
@ARTICLE{
 author={}
 date={}
 journal={}
 }

@ARTICLE{
author={}
date={}
journal={}
}
```

I am trying to use split() to isolate the articles, then check if the articles have empty fields. Here is my code:

```
try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Latex1.bib"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line =null;

            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                String [] info = line.split("@ARTICLE"); 

                for(int x=0; x<info.length;x++) {
                    System.out.println(info[x]);
                }
             }
```

I can't seem to find a way to split the file into Articles by knowing that all the information is surrounded by @ARTICLE{ }. Is there a way to split a file into segments based on a known format for it's enclosing body?

Comment: What did you expect and what did you get? It seems as if it might kinda work, even though it will produce empty space and annoying enclosing braces...

Comment: No it can work obviously because you are reading line by line, the only way this could work is if you loaded first all the file into a string and then use split. But it might be a bad idea if the file is big, instead maybe you should just handle the stream of characters yourself and use states (booleans or enum values) to follow where you are in the stream (like `isInArticle` or something like that).

Comment: Would you be alright with using RegEx? Because that would really simplify everything.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I am getting exactly that, what I want is to be able to store each article in a separate String and then search that String for authors, date, journal etc. to eventually transfer it into a different biblography format. I can't seem to get that to happen.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder that was my initial plan, but unfortunately, I spoke to my professor and I can only use the Scanner and IO libraries.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin sorry I meant the IO classes, Scanner class, and StringTokenizer class not libraries. Can't argue with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer without `RegEx` and `split()`

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try
{
    fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Pingle/Desktop/Text.txt");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
Scanner ob = new Scanner(fis);
ob.useDelimiter("\n");
String str = "";
boolean started = false;
int ArticleNumber = 0;
while(ob.hasNext())
{
    String line = ob.next();
    if(line.trim().contains("{") && !started)
    {
        started = true;
        ArticleNumber++;
        continue;
    }
    if(line.trim().startsWith("}"))
    {
        started = false;
        System.out.println("Article "+ArticleNumber+" contains:\n"+str);
    }
    if(started)
    {
        str += line+"\n";
    }
}
```

When you said `Scanner`, I immediately thought of `FileInputStream`, but it also works with `FileReader` with a few tweaks.

Also, I used a `txt` file but it'll work with a `bib` file too.

So the Scanner takes all the code of the file, and using the separator of `\n` every time you call `next()` it takes a new line.

`started` checks whether the line is enclosed by the `Article`'s Braces, and also checks whether the line is a content of the `Article`.

If `started` is false and the line has a `{`, then it means that `str` should start storing the lines, and `started` becomes `true`.
When the line starts with a `}`, then `started` becomes false, and it checks for another Article.

Comment: thanks! this is great. Is there a way that the String str won't store the previous articles. For example I get Article 3 contains: and then it displays the content from article 1 ,2 and 3.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, after System.out.println("Article "+ArticleNumber+" contains:\n"+str); I just set str to = " ", then it basically "erases" the previous content in the String

Comment: @praventz If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references :)